# joining output from two cmdlets

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I wanted to get the GivenName, Surname and Department info out of AD and the following works:

```
Get-ADGroupMember XXXX-servicecenter | Get-ADUser  | Select GivenName,Surname, @{Name="Dept";Expression={Get-ADObject -Properties department -Identity "$_" | Select -Expand Department}}
```

However if I remove the `-Properties department` bit it doesn't return the department info. Can someone please explain why I have to specifically include that? Thanks.

Comment: The AD Module cmdlets wont query all object's attributes by default, you must ask for those attributes to query hence the need to use `-Properties`. It would be extremely inefficient other way. Other than that, you're querying the same object 2 times for no particular reason `| Get-ADUser -Properties Department | Select GivenName,Surname,DepartMent`

Comment: You may (re-)read the help for [Get-ADUser -Properties *](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-properties). The cmdlet returns only a subset of properties by default. If you want to have more than this subset you have to specify the properties your're after.  [Get-ADUser Outputs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#outputs)

Comment: Many cmdlets only return default properties and not all properties.  To get all properties you have to pipe output to | Select-Object -Property * or specify non default properties like you did in your code.

Comment: Thanks all, that make sense now. And thanks Santiago for pointing out the Department info is already returned by Get-ADUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf) has provided the crucial pointers in their comment, `Get-ADUser` only outputs a specific set of attributes by default, this is mainly because returning all user objects attributes for each query would be very inefficient. See [`-Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-properties) parameter and [**Outputs**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#outputs) for more details.

As for your code in question, you're querying the same user 2 times, once while piping the output from `Get-ADGroupMember` and twice in the expression used in `Select-Object`. It's also worth noting that groups can have other object types aside from AD Users thus it's recommend to filter the output before piping it to `Get-ADUser`:

```bash
Get-ADGroupMember XXXX-servicecenter |
    Where-Object objectClass -eq user |
    Get-ADUser -Properties department |
    Select-Object GivenName, Surname, Department
```

There is a simpler and faster way to accomplish the same by using Active Directory filtering capabilities. See [about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10))
 and [Active Directory: LDAP Syntax Filters](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx).

```bash
$filter = '(memberof={0})' -f (Get-ADGroup XXXX-servicecenter).DistinguishedName
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter $filter -Properties department |
    Select-Object GivenName, Surname, Department
```